# PhpStorm: How to show exactly number of matches in Find in Path?

Tags: find, phpstorm

In PhpStorm I use **Edit > Find > Find in Path** to find a word. But it show  the message **"100+ matches in 50+ files"**.

I would like the message to show the **exactly** number of matches and files.

[image: PhpStorm showing FIND IN PATH]

Comment: It's a Preview .. so it shows top 100 only. If you want to see all matches, please click on "Open in Find Window" at the bottom and you will see ALL results (it will open the same tool window that was used before this preview was introduced).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that results in the "Find in Path" popup are **just a preview** *(very multifunctional one, you can edit the text right there... but still just a preview)* so it shows TOP 100 results only. For some popular words you may see only a single file found as it may have all 100+ hits there.

If you want to see all matches, please click on `Open in Find Window` button at the bottom right (<kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> on most keymaps) and you will see ALL results (it will open standard Find Results tool window that was used before this preview was introduced).

[image]

From https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187379#focus=streamItem-27-2382897.0-0

> We limit the amount to avoid performance problem, as it searches immediately on every keystroke - imagine how slow it would be if we look through all sources.

Also note that the search here is done in multiple threads in order to show you any results as fast as possible (so you can check if it finds what you need or if you need to adjust your text (e.g. due to a typo etc.)) That's why the results will in a rather random order and will change the positions if another search for the same text is executed.

From https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187379#focus=streamItem-27-2724126.0-0

> Actually, we limit search results with the first 100 occurrences because it's designed to be a preview UI. When there are dozens of found occurrences you can easily overview all of them and navigate exactly to the place you're looking for, otherwise you switch to the full result set in Find Tool Window.

---

There is an open ticket about improvements in this regard: how to make it more obvious to notice that there are more matches available, as not everyone can even spot the "100+ matches in 50+ files" text (the way how it is displayed on your original screenshot -- the text on the right of the search field).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196723 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on any progress.

**UPDATE 2021-12-14:** For a while the "100+ matches in 50+ files" text is much easier to spot -- it is shown at the top left corner now.

---

Please note that 100 is not hardcoded constant but a default value. You can adjust `ide.usages.page.size` IDE property (`Help | Edit Custom Properties...` action) and set it to a bigger value (may affect other search related stuff as well).

Since search happens after each key press (after a small delay AFAIK) and your project is large... it will affect performance if you set it to the large value. I think it's not that hard to press <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> to see all matches (even if it's over 1000 of them)...

**UPDATE 2021-12-14:**

As of 2021.3 version you can edit that value right in the IDE Settings:

[image]

Comment: Edit Custom Properties shows a empty file. Do you know how to configure it? Also I like "Find in Path" popup because it shows lines of the code where the word was found.

Comment: *"Edit Custom Properties shows a empty file. Do you know how to configure it?"* That file does not even exists by default ... so it will be empty. It uses similar format to `.ini` files, so something like `ide.usages.page.size=200` will work. NOTE -- that file is read on IDE start only. You would need to restart IDE to see the changes

Comment: *"Also I like "Find in Path" popup because it shows lines of the code where the word was found."* Find Results tool window does the same, it can show editable preview area on the right side (e.g. I can make changes in multiple files and then upload them without even opening them in Editor). Multiple grouping options are also available (e.g. show each match as separate entry or group few from the same line as 1 etc)